# Can I conditionally render Livewire components on my page (as one can in Vue)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm attempting to design a project in Laravel. I ran the following command to initialize the project: "laravel new demo --jet". When prompted to choose between inertia and livewire I chose livewire as I've heard better things about it.

A little back story, I'm about 2-3 weeks into learning Laravel and I've never used livewire before, although I am very familiar with using Javascript and am very experienced with Vue.js. I've looked elsewhere for a solution to my problem but now I'm not quite sure if Laravel even supports exactly what I'm looking for.

**TL/DR:**
**I'm wondering what the best practice would be for rendering child components on a page**. I would like to create a dashboard that has several options to choose from on the left side of the page. When a user selects an option, I'd like for a corresponding component to appear in the center of the page. If a user were to select a different option, the original child component would disappear and a new corresponding child component would become visible.

Ideally, I'd like to avoid using the router for this, although that might just be because I'm not entirely comfortable with using it. I do understand it's pretty heavily integrated into the Laravel workflow. As I mentioned, I'm used to using Vue where you can easily integrate JS functionality into your html and use conditional statements to hide/show child components without changing routes.

If anything I've said above is causing any confusion, let me know. Thanks.

**P.S. If anyone has any good resources for learning livewire & laravel together please let me know about them! Laracasts has been great but I think Laravel recently updated their auth scaffolding and it's causing some confusion for me.**

Comment: Stack is for code examples that accompanies a question. What have you tried already?